# Financial responsibilities for Custodian of (minor) international student

Tags: canada, minor, ontario

hoping this question is in scope here.

Ok, first some background.

Canada, Ontario. Toronto area if it matters.

My wife and I have decided to act as a Homestay guardian/custodian for an international student. She is a minor (16 yr old) and attending Secondary school. The child's parents will remain in China.

The family is a friend of ours, so there isn't any major immediate legal "panic" :) We know each other, and we both have at least a basic level of trust. (ie we aren't trying to scam each other).

We got our guardianship notarised, as required.
We got insurance setup as required.

Chatting with the wife, however, one thought came up. "What if" scenario.  What if an accident occurs, and a hospital bill arises beyond what insurance covers.

Who is responsible for paying that?

Our current arrangement/understanding is that the child's parents will cover all financial issues (we provide house, food, and basic transportation). However, that is mostly a verbal arrangement.

As the notarised guardian, I actually suspect, (as far as the government is concerned), I would be the one responsible. Is that correct?  It would then be up to me to get reimbursed from the parents on my own ?

I did some searching around, however, any search with the word "financial" starts talking about the minor's assets/property/etc.  which isn't really what we're after here :)

So for now, just trying to do some high level research / digging.  If needed, I'll consult a lawyer for "more better" clarification if needed. Just hoping to avoid that hassle if it's not really needed.

Links to related material definitely welcomed :)

Thanks!